# Conduction in liquid and gas

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, convection, thermal-conduction

[image]

Is this condition correct, "if liquid and gas heated **from top**, then it will be possible for 'conduction' to occur" ?

One reason i can think is :

when liquid or gas is heated from sideways or below,the heat transfer will take place through 'convection' and not through 'conduction'.

And only when we heat from top, there will be no 'convection'. And thus there is a chance for conduction?

Source(for on top no convection):
https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/it-it-possible-to-heat-a-liquid-or-gas-from-above/

So my doubt is the statement correct?

Comment: Heating from below is the result of both heat conduction and convection (heat flow assisted by fluid movement).

Comment: Like the statement is trying to say , that conduction lf heat in solid and liquid is only possible only when its heated from top only. I am confused, when i read this, i think the statement is wrong but when i thought of how it will go for convection then it seems right?

Comment: @ChetMiller , heating from below will have heat transferred through both conduction and convection, did i understand correctly? Thank you so much

Comment: Convection heat transfer is the esult of fluid movement and conduction normal to isotherms.  If there is no fluid movement, then only conduction normal to isotherms is present.  Thus, fluid movement enhances the rate of heat conduction.

Comment: @ChetMiller, what is 'normal to isotherms'? Thank you

Comment: @ChetMiller, also is the statement correct or not? Like if it talks about conduction is not possible even with convection like just not possible if heated from sideways or below, then the statement is wrong by your comment like it happens just along convection. but If the statement talks (means/imply) about 'only' conduction and not with convection, then, it can only happen from top, something like that, is this correct? Thank you so much

Comment: Well, t would call it impressive rather than incorrect.  I think that you have interpreted the situation correctly.

Comment: Heat transfer by conduction is always possible within a gas or a liquid. I think what the text author had in mind though is that it's hard to _demonstrate_ that conduction is happening when convection happens at the same time. Convection is a far more effective means of distributing the heat, and it will mask whatever amount of conduction is happening at the same time.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I think you could go as far as saying convection and conduction are ultimately modeling the same process, just conduction makes use of simplifications when the medium itself cannot flow.  As far as I'm aware, convection models already account for the "conduction" as part of their calculation (and it's hard to imagine them not doing that, given how traditional heat transfer uses a lot of empirical information to solve problems).

Answer (score 0):

Metals are much better conductors than non-metals?

In general, maybe, but diamond is a better heat conductor than metals, if I remember correctly

Comment: at $>200W/(m\cdot K)$ so is $BeO$, better than most metals, good enough for the poorer engineers among us